# Sorting scope by boolean values (rails model)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting, scope, boolean

I have two views generated from a Pins model (user/show and pins/index).

On the users/show, I want to use the default scope to show all the pins.
On the pins/index, I want to use the featured_order scope to show the "featured" pins at the top, then continue by the default scope.

Here's what I have but for some reason it is reverting to the default scope for everything.

```
class Pin < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :title

  belongs_to :user

  # for sorting featured and newest pins first
  default_scope order: 'created_at DESC'
  scope :featured_order, order('(case when featured then 1 else 0 end) DESC, created_at DESC')
end
```

In my index.html.erb I render a partial (_pin.html.erb):

```
<%= render @pins %>
```

In my show.html.erb I have a list:

```
<% @pins.each do |pin| %>
    <%= pin.title %>
    <%= pin.content %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the index controller

```
@pins = Pin.featured_order
```

Then you can iterate over it.
This will sort by featured order and resort to default_scope if needed.

If this doesn't work, you're best bet would be to create to scopes and use the as needed instead of default scope.

I always err on the side of using [default scope](http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/806-default_scope-is-evil).

Comment: You are right, default_scope was taking over everything. So I ended up removing it and creating a separate scope for the users/show